# Rename [creeper-world-3-ae] → [creeper-world-3-arc-eternal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, I'd like to suggest renaming the tag for [*Creeper World 3: Arc Eternal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeper_World#Creeper_World_3:_Arc_Eternal) as follows:

- [creeper-world-3-ae](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creeper-world-3-ae) → [creeper-world-3-arc-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creeper-world-3-arc-eternal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done! :)

- [creeper-world-3-ae](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creeper-world-3-ae) → [creeper-world-3-arc-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creeper-world-3-arc-eternal)